# How to find the occurences of the elements of first cell array in second cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, find, cell

I have two cell arrays:

```
A={'abc','pai','abd','pa/n/v/d'}

B={'pai-pro','abc','pai','abd/','abd','pa/n/v/d','abd-','pa/n/v/d','pai-pro'}
```

I need a code to find the occurrence of the elements of A in B. Such that the output would be:

```
'abc' = 1

'pai' = 3

'abd' = 3

'pa/n/v/d' = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
for i = 1:length(A)
   sum(cell2mat(strfind(cellstr(B),A{i})))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For each element of `A`, you can do the following to get its occurrence in `B`

```
[isPresent, index] = ismember(A{1}, B)
```

The `index` will contain the location of the element `A{i}` in `B` if it is present indicated by the `isPresent` variable.